# Force qt-vlc to don't hide mouse cursor

Tags: qt, qt5, libvlc, vlc-qt, wincc

I'm developing a video stream software, I'm using libvlc and qt-vlc for playing videos from network stream. Everything is good just one problem. When VlcMediaPlayer starts to playing, the mouse pointer hide over VlcWidgetVideo widget.

If mouse move around application it will be shown but only on the VlcWidgetVideo there are no mouse

My simple code is like that:

```
auto _instance = new VlcInstance(VlcCommon::args(), this);
auto _player = new VlcMediaPlayer(_instance);
auto playerWidget = new VlcWidgetVideo(_player, this);
auto _media = new VlcMedia(mediaUrl.toString(), _instance);
_player->setVideoWidget(playerWidget);
_player->play();
// mediaUrl is type of QUrl
_player->open(_media);
```

Now, my question is that: How can I force qt-vlc to don't hide pointer? I want to mouse pointer be visible always. My development environment is:

- CentOS 7.2 on VirtualBox
- Qt 5.5

Excuse for my bad English

**Note 1:**

Two points:

- Playing same stream video with vlc media player on same computer doesn't hide the cursor!
- When I try to simulate the mouse pointer with a shape in QLabel the player widget flush by repeat

**Note 2:**

I dropped using of qt-vlc and used libvlc directly, But no changes! Mouse hide and some times it appear as a single black pixel

**Note 3:**

Running same code on debian 9 works fine

Answer (score 0):

Use `--mouse-hide-timeout=<integer>` from https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help/

If that doesn't work, consider opening an issue as I'm not sure vlc-qt offers a way to configure that option.

Comment: Thanks. I've tested this before. But no changes affected.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer if that fixes your problem, or let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: No, that's not solved my problem. As I note I'm using libvlc. not vlc media player.

Comment: Read the [doc](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__core.html#ga915aa5778053d7b52ff9f6ba6e2f7764). You can pass those flags to libvlc.

Comment: --mouse-hide-timeout is for fullscreen mode, My problem occur in normal window.